# Adding data, class and style to HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, database, methods

I've been struggling for a while with this exercise(below my HTML code):

```
<div class="exercise ex5">
    <h1>Zadanie 5</h1>
    <ul>
        <li data-direction="down"><a class="scroll"  href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li data-direction="down"><a class="scroll"  href="#about">about</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#team">team</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#service">service</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
        <li data-direction="down"><a class="scroll"  href="#blog">blog</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I need to do is:
1.add data-direction with value "up" to each element, that doesn't have it yet

```
var lol = document.querySelectorAll(".ex5 li");
    for (var i =0;i<lol.length;i++) {
        if (lol[i].hasAttribute === false) {
    lol[i].setAttribute("data-direction", "up");
        };
        lol[4].hasAttribute("data-direction");
        console.log(lol[i]);
    };
```

Maybe I should use :not... ?

2.Add "big" class to fifth element of my list

```
var lol = document.querySelectorAll(".ex5 li");
    for (var i =0;i<lol.length;i++) {
        lol:nth-child(5).classList.add("big");
        };
```

3.Underline every third element of my list.

```
var lol = document.querySelectorAll(".ex5 li");
    for (var i =0;i<lol.length;i++) {
        lol:nth-child(-3n+6).style.textDecorationLine="underline";
        };
```

This is what I've been trying to do so far.. none of my codes is running, I'm very beggining at coding, just started my course and everything is very confusing for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:

```
var lol = document.querySelectorAll(".ex5 li");
for (var i =0;i<lol.length;i++) {
    if (!lol[i].hasAttribute("data-direction")) {
        lol[i].setAttribute("data-direction", "up");
    }
};
```

2:

```
var lol = document.querySelector(".ex5 li:nth-child(5)");
lol.classList.add("big");
```

3:

```
var lol = document.querySelectorAll(".ex5 li:nth-child(-3n+6)");
for (var i =0;i<lol.length;i++) {
    lol[i].style.textDecorationLine="underline";
}
```